# Can anyone explain the name of every distribution of ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it must be very interesting.`Diamondback` means come back with glory?The Image of every distribution is really fantastic.[here](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261759/can-anyone-explain-the-name-of-every-distribution-of-ros?/) by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-05-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS release names are based on / inspired by turtle species names (the animals). I'm not sure they actually 'mean' anything apart from what mental imagery they evoke.

The names are typically chosen after consultation with the community:

- [ROS H](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2012-May/051561.html)
- [ROS-I](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2013-January/052554.html)
- [ROS-J](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2014-April/068441.html)
- [ROS-K](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2015-May/069333.html)
- [ROS L](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2016-April/069899.html)
- [ROS-M](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2017-April/071041.html)

As to why turtles are used, I think it's *turtles all the way down*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [little_bob](https://answers.ros.org/users/30063/little_bob/) on 2017-05-15**:
Thanks.Hope I can learn it better.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2020-03-18**:
As for "why turtles", looks like I duplicated/reiterated the question in #q347023 (and came up with a little different answer).